# Square integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone please help me to answer this question:

> We consider $V\in E_r=\{P\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d]\ ∣\ \deg(P)\le r\}$. If $e^{−V(x)}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then the limit of $V$ as $|x|$ goes to $\infty$ is $+\infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. $V$ is a polynomial, isn't it? Then why is this question related to PDEs? Maybe you could find better tags.

Comment: we have the possible limits of a polynomial V of degree greater or equal to 1 as |x| goes to +∞ are +∞ or -∞.But i dont know how to prove in our case that the limit is +∞.can someone help?

Comment: Try to prove the contrapositive. Assume that $$\lim_{|x|\to\infty} V < +\infty$$ and check that in that case $e^{-V(x)}\not\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: if we suppose that $lim_{|x|→∞}V<+∞$ thus there exist $a,b \in  R$ such that  $a\le V(x)\le b $ hence  $exp(-b)\le exp(-V(x))\le exp(-a)$ or $exp(-b)$ is not in $L^2$ thus  $exp(-V(x))$ isn't in $ L^2$
what i wrote is right?

Comment: Yes. Note that the only bound for $V$ that is necessary is the one from above, that is, bounding $e^{-V(x)}$ from below.

Comment: the contradiction of " the limite of V as |x| goes to +∞ is +∞" is $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} V < +\infty $ or $ \lim_{|x|\to\infty} V = -\infty $ .In the case  $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} V = -\infty $ what should i do ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove the contrapositive. Assume that
$$\lim_{|x|\to\infty} V < +\infty \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and check that in that case $e^{−V(x)}\not\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Note that in that case $V(x)\le b$ as $|x|\to\infty$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and, hence, $e^{-V(x)}\ge e^{-b}$, which is not in $L^2$. Moreover, whether limit \eqref{1} is finite or goes to $-\infty$ is irrelevant. The latter would be even worse, since in that case $e^{-V(x)}\to+\infty$.

Comment: and if $e^{-V(x)}\to+\infty$ how we can prove that the integral is not finite?

Comment: can i write in this case that there exist $A\ge 0$ such that for $|x|\ge A$ we have $exp(−V(x))\ge 1$ hence $\int_{R^n}|exp(−V(x))|^2dx\ge \int_{|x|≥A}1dx=\infty$?

Comment: For a function to be in $L^2$ it is mandatory that the tails vanish (go to 0) at $\infty$. As you deduced above, if the limit of $V$ is a constant (which, by the way, is not possible for polynomials), then the tails do not vanish, they converge to another constant too. And if the limit of $V$ is $-\infty$ then, the tails of $e^{-V}$ do not even converge. If the integral of a constant on a infinite domain is infinite, imagine the integral of infinite on an infinite domain...

Comment: yes i can imagine that but we should prove this fact using a mathematical raisonment

Comment: But that's the argument. In your comment above you bound the function by A from below, right? And the case when $V\to-\infty$ fits there, doesn't it? By the way, use that $e^{-V(x)}\ge C>0$ instead of $e^{-V(x)}\ge1$.

Comment: ok thanks .i want also to prove that if V is a polynomial such that limit of V as |x| goes to ∞ is +∞ then V admets a local minimum. How should i prove that?

Comment: You should ask that in a new question and accept/upvote this answer if you think it fulfills your requirements

Comment: i think we have to treat an other case:if V doesn't have any limit as |x| goes to $+\infty$ .But i don't know how to deal with it .can you please help me?

Comment: That would not be the case of polynomials (that, except constants, only have either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ limit). Nevertheless, I'm afraid I can't help you with that. I think the best for you would be to open a new question.

Comment: if we take the example of V(x)=x we have V doesn't have a limit as |X| goes to $+\infty$.